# Best practice Sitecore Placeholder in rendering, share content

Tags: rendering, sitecore, placeholder

Im sure this has been asked before, but as far as I can see no one seems to mention the best practice for this case.

I have a body-placeholder that basically wraps everything of my page.. with in this placeholder the user is allowed to add "Section Renderings" each section rendering contains two additional Placeholders...
When adding two or more Section rendering however.. they seem to share the content that gets added in their two placeholders... and I guess this is since the placeholders are all sharing the same name..

Whats the best practice for this?.. I have read about people creating extensions of Html.Sitecore() and adding a what they refer to as a "Dynamic Placeholder"..

But well my question remains :).. whats the best practice for solving this issue?

Comment: It's a known limitation. You need to use dynamic placeholders: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134720/sitecore-dynamic-placeholders-with-mvc

Answer (score 1):

@jammykam is correct. Sitecore does not support dynamic placeholders out of the box and you will need to implement an extension built by a third-party, or build your own version that meets your needs.

Personally, having had to dig into this a little in the past, I do not recommend starting from scratch and trying to figure it out. The available resources from other folks who have done the hard work will get you much further.