# Adding component on top of the existing one in sitecore 8.1 MVC goes down bottom in other language

Tags: sitecore, components, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8.1, experience-editor

I have created a Spacer module and applied placeholder settings accordingly. I want to add this module on top of existing one so I clicked on Component button display in top ribbon menu.Then Clicked on **Add here**. This module is added on top of one existing one But when I clicked on Save button and on page load this Space module move down to below existing one. Couldn't understand why?
Even it's working fine in English(en) version but having this issue in french version of website.

I have implemented following for Dynamic Placeholder [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134720/sitecore-dynamic-placeholders-with-mvc/30514133#30514133)

Thanks